# What are the best practices of storing data for dynamic content in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Basically, I'm creating a simple brochure website that can change contents dynamically using Javascript. Every time the button is clicked, it calls a function in the .js file which inserts it to the html. To do this, I put these data into a variable in the .js file. The problem is that I find the data too large and is cluttering the .js file.

```html
<button class="content-1">
<button class="content-2">

<div class="container">
  # change between content 1 and 2
</div>
```

```js
// in my case there are more than 2 contents
// each content has other contents as well
// the question is where to put these data 

let contentOne = [ 
  "a lot of text data", 
  "a lot of text data",
  "a lot of text data"
]

# other code
```

For now I managed to separate them into another .js file. But I'm just wondering, is there a cleaner way to store and then access these data? Like using YAML ? How do you usually do it ?

For dynamic websites I realize it's usually stored in databases, but how is it for static websites

Comment: You can use local storage or indexeddb to store data.

Comment: you can store data in JSON file and read it with jquery.getJson(). https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: The best way might be to store it in a different file, then load and parse it lazily using AJAX... But that's a really opinion-based question, that isn't well suited on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it in a different file as JSON. Then in your HTML file, you have a function that does a fetch request to get the JSON file from the server.

This does mean that you need a webserver while you are developing. You can use a light-weight one like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Then, your code does something like this:

```
function hydrateData() {
  return fetch('data.json').then(response => response.json());
}

hydrateData().then(data => {

// the rest of your code that needs the data goes in here

})
```